# What is this plant, weed or wildflower?

Tags: identification, weeds, wildflowers

I am hoping it will be a wildflower, as it is spread throughout our school wildflower garden, but no buds yet. [image]

Comment: Is the stem square sided or round? Just twirl the stem in your fingers to feel.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like mint. Can you break off a leave and spell to see if it's a mint.

Comment: It isn't mint, I know what you mean, the leaves look somewhat like that with a fuzzy texture. But the leaves are much larger than mint. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [lemon balm](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/grow-your-own/herbs/lemon-balm) - rub the leaves, do they have a mostly-citrus, slightly-minty aroma?